# Is there an academic field that explores how to create the best political system?

Tags: political-system, checks-and-balances

I was thinking about the qualities of a perfect system involving human beings.  Is there an academic discipline that explores this topic?

For example, a perfect political system would require accountability.  Each party/entity would need someone or something to keep each of them accountable.  Who or what is best to keep each accountable?

But, these ideas can also be applied to a business organization or other facets of our society.  For example, in schools, teachers should be held accountable if their students perform poorly, but such checks are only loosely put in place.

Comment: "a perfect system involving human beings": many would argue that that's an oxymoron, as any system involving humans cannot possibly be perfect.

Comment: Political science, social psychology, philosophy

Comment: Surely the answer is simply "Politics" -  I find this question odd; it is like asking on the Astronomy site if there is an academic field that studies the nature of heavenly bodies. Can you clarify why this "obvious" answer is not what you want?

Comment: Would "Marxism-Leninism" qualify? (building Communism)? Results of this science are another story.

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff: One could replace "perfect" with "best possible", though - but then one will still need to supply a metric, the choice of which will be fundamentally not objective.

Comment: James, I am asking because I don't know where to look.  For example, in my opinion, an important trait of a robust political system should be a system in which every entity/party is held immediately accountable with both positive and negative feedback.  I can't seem to find any discussion of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much what political science is about (at least in some of its subdisciplines), although parts of the question are also addressed by philosophy (more in classical philosophy, e.g., Plato’s *Republic*, but determining the question of what is good is still very much in the realm of philosophy) and organizational psychology which looks at how institutions/groups of people interact and how those interactions can be shaped.

Comment: So, where would I look?  I have been looking...  I mentioned this in another comment.  Oen important trait is that each entity is immediately accountable.  This seems so obvious but systems aren't set up to effect this.  Why?  Where do I find more information about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the **history** is the science you need, if properly done (analysis, not just a bunch of events with dates attached). It does not explain how to build the better society but it should explain what happened in the past and also why. It should tell which facts are true, which fake, and which society forces were involved. It already gave us lots of lessons on how to build a good enough society but we are students with chicken memory.

Each ideology has the own science how to build the society aligned to that ideology. Liberalism, Marxism-Leninism, Fundamentalism, Nazism and others without end will provide numerous arguments and explanations why they view is good, why others are not. Each has the own science that serves them well.

Comment: Would you know where specifically I can look?